# How can i style my div border to look lie the image below

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I want to style my div to border to look like the image below, its a div that has a ul and li tags with images inside, here is my code

test.page.scss

```
.renderList{
    position: relative;
    bottom: 1%;
    border: red;
}
ul {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    list-style-type: none;
    height: 9% !important;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: transparent;
}
li {
    float: left;
    display: table-cell;
}
img{
    height: 50px !important;
}
```

test.page.html

```
<div id="renderList">
            <ul class="bb">
                <li *ngFor="let img of Imgs">
                    <img [style.width.px]="PixWidth" [src]="img.imgUrl"/>
                </li>
            </ul>           
            <div class="wrap" role="group" aria-labelledby="multi-lbl">
                <label class="sr-only" for="a">Value A:</label>
                <input (change)="onChangeVal(1)" name="min" id="a" type="range" min="0" [max]="VidDuration" [(ngModel)]="range.min"/>
                <label class="sr-only" for="b">Value B:</label>
                <input (change)="onChangeVal(2)" name="max" id="b" type="range" min="0" [max]="VidDuration" [(ngModel)]="range.max"/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

here is the image i want my div border to look like
[image: The Image]

How can i style the div border to look like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/dav9p0u2/), I added the border and few elements to make it look like it is in the image.

Basically I created empty `div` elements for the side elements with `pseudo-elements` for white line inside.

Hope it helps.